# Wicket 6 PageParameters empty on Chrome and Opera

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have migrated my web application from Wicket 1.4 up to 6.21.

Everything is working fine on Firefox, but on other browsers (tested on Chrome and Opera) on some pages PageParameters are empty.

I checked POST requests and looks the same on each of mentioned browsers. Addresses on each browser are also the same and containing param I want to use.

My constructor:

```
public MyPage(PageParameters params) {
    super(params);
    id = params.get(ID_PARAM).toInteger();
    // do stuff;
}
```

causes (of course):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

My knowledge about Wicket is rather limited, but app on Firefox is really working fine, so I want to run it on Chrome also.

Any answers or even advice what should I check are very welcome.
Of course I can provide some additional details and code.

EDIT:

Here is screenshot of POST on Chrome (on server PageParameters are empty):
[image: POST screenshot on Chrome]

While debugging I encounter really strange behavior. On `MyPage` there is `AcceptButton` which redirects to `AnotherPage`.

Using Firefox clicking `AcceptButton` results entering `AcceptButton#onSubmit` method, which is calling `setResponsePage(AnotherPage, params)`.

Using Chrome clicking `AcceptButton` results entering `MyPage()` constructor, without entering `AcceptButton#onSubmit` nor `AcceptButton#onError`, so somehow it tries reload MyPage.

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a demo application then please create a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET and we will debug ! I don't see any reason why it doesn't work on Chrome. Check in Chrome's Dev Tools that it actually sends the POST parameters.

Comment: @martin-g I provided screenshot of POST request from Chrome. It redirects to error page (in response), because of empty PageParameters. Maybe I will try to create demo to reproduce, but it will probably take few days.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why Firefox works but in the attached image we can see that this is an **Ajax** request, so it should not go to MyPage constructor at all.

The Ajax request is targeted against AcceptButton (an AjaxButton, I guess) so the post parameters could be read in `AcceptButton#onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget, Form)` with `getRequest().getPostParameters()`.

Maybe you redirect to MyPage with `setResponsePage()` or something like this but the Ajax request parameter(s) will not be automatically forwarded to the page's PageParameters in this case.

Comment: I updated my description. Firefox indeed enters `AcceptButton#onSubmit` and redirects through `setResponsePage()`, but Chrome do not even enter `onSubmit` but `MyPage()` contructor.